# n-place mastermind variation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, probability

A few days ago I came across such a problem at the contest my uni was holding:

> Given the history of guesses in a mastermind game using digits instead
>   of colors in a form of pairs (x, y) where x is the guess and y is how
>   many digits were placed correctly, guess the correct number. Each
>   input is guaranteed to have a solution.
>
> Example for a 5-place game:
>
> (90342, 2)
>    (70794, 0)
>   (39458, 2)
>   (34109, 1)
>    (51545, 2)
>   (12531, 1)
>
> Should yield:
>
> 39542
>
> Create an algorithm to correctly guess the result in an n-place
>   mastermind given the history.

So the only idea I had was to keep the probability of each digit being correct based on the correct shots in a given guess and then try to generate the most possible number, then the next one and so on - so for example we'd have 9 being 40% possible for the first place (cause the first guess has 2/5=40% correct), 7 being impossible and so on. Then we do the same for other places in the number and finally generate a number with the highest probability to test it against all the guesses.

The problem with this approach, though, is that generating the next possible number, and the next, and so on (as we probably won't score a home run in the first try) is really non-trivial (or at least I don't see an easy way of implementing this) and since this contest had something like a 90 minute timeframe and this wasn't the only problem, I don't think something so elaborate was the anticipated approach.

So how could one do it easier?

Comment: Sounds to me you can use a constraint programming tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Probability does not apply here.  In this case a number is either right or wrong.  There is no "partially right".

For 5 digits you can just test all 100,000 possible numbers against the given history and throw out the ones where the matches are incorrect.  This approach becomes impractical for larger numbers at some point.  You will be left with a list of numbers that meet the criteria.  If there is exactly one in the list, then you have solved it.

python code, where `matches` counts the matching digits of its 2 parameters:

```
for k in range(0,100000):
    if matches(k,90342)==2 and matches(k,70794)==0 and matches(k,39458)==2 and matches(k,34109)==1 and matches(k,51545)==2 and matches(k,12531):
        print k
```

prints:

```
39542
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that comes to mind is to write a routine that can generally filter an enumeration of combinations based on a particular *try* and its score.

So for your example, you would initially pick one of the most constrained *tries* (one of the ones with a score of 2) as a filter and then enumerate all combinations that satisfy it.

The output from that enumeration is then used as input to a filter run for the next unprocessed *try*, and so on, until the list of *tries* is exhausted.

The candidate *try* that comes out of the final enumeration is the solution.